# how to build dll files in netbeans using ms vc++ compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, netbeans6.8

i tried using cygwin gcc compiler  along with netbeans to create dll files it seems there is an issue in the generated dll file. if i use the ms vc++ compiler and do all compiling on command line its runs file, but i dont know how to integrate ms vc++ tools in netbeans ... can anyone help me on that ?

thanks
jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans doesn't provide a way to integrate microsoft compiler in its IDE. This is probably because it doens't have rights to do so. With NetBeans you can integrate only GNU compilers for C/C++. To use Microsoft C/C++ compiler, you have to use MS Visual Studio IDE, or MS Visual Studio provided command line tools.